# Can a vector::iterator also function as a vector

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, buffer

So I am trying to load a binary file into a Vector, so I can use it like a Buffer.

```
ifstream binaryFile;
vector<unsigned char> fileBuffer(istreambuf_iterator<char>(binaryFile), {});
vector<unsigned char>::iterator fileIter = fileBuffer.begin();
```

Now my question is, if I use the `fileIter` variable, can I access all the elements in the `fileBuffer` vector ?
I want to know, because I need to edit the contents of the `fileBuffer` only at certain Positions, that is why I am working with iterators in the first place.

In a nutshell, I want to know if the content of the vector `fileBuffer` will change, according to edits made to the `fileIter` with code like
`*(fileIter + 2) = 'a';`

I have researched this Topic but I have not yet found an answer.

Comment: It sounds like you're expecting to modify the contents of the file by modifying the vector, but there is no connection between them.

Comment: You modify `fileBuffer` (i.e., the vector) though the iterator, not the file.

Comment: @molbdnilo i want to modify the vector and then save the vector as a new file.

Comment: @眠りネロク so are you saying, if i edit the iterator, I will also edit the vector ?

Comment: @youngtrashbag I mean, you will only edit the vector, not the file. The vector is a copy of the file contents.

Comment: @youngtrashbag I think you just need to to this: 1. Read the file into the vector. 2. Edit the contents of the vector. 3. write the vector to the file (or another file?).

Comment: @眠りネロク Thank you that is all I needed to know :)

Comment: @Jabberwocky I have already done that but I need to find a string in the file, from where on i need to edit, say, 5 bytes.

Comment: @youngtrashbag OK, but then where is the problem? Does your code work or not? Your question might be a [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You need to clarify. [Edit] your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard class template std::vector has a random access iterator. So you can use it the same way as a pointer. For example

```
fileIter[10] = 'A';
```

or

```
fileIter += 10;
```

and so on.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    for ( const auto &item : v ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    auto it = v.begin();

    it[1] = -it[1];

    for ( const auto &item : v ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    it += 2;

    *it *= 10;

    for ( const auto &item : v ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
1 2 3 4 5 
1 -2 3 4 5 
1 -2 30 4 5
```